# elegant ie6 hover css solution

Tags: css

I want a solution for tag:hover that is not working on ie6. My guess is it has to be done with javascript.

I found this patch: csshover3.htc (http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html), I checked it's demo! and i didn't work on my ie6 browser!

There has to be an elegant way to solve this very BIG and basic problem, may be a jquery plugin.

Any lead is appriciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using jQuery you would be able to use the hover function (http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover) to add a class on hover.

example:

```
$("li").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass('ie6-hover');
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass('ie6-hover');
  }
);
```

You could then make the class have the same properties.

```
li:hover, li.ie6-hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Easy solution on a per tag basis.  I would recommend in his case also applying a specific class to limit the number of matches on a page.

Answer (score 1):

A short jQuery Plugin does it for me

```
 IE6TableHover: function()
    {
        if(jQuery.browser.msie && /6.0/.test(navigator.userAgent))
        {
            $(this).hover(
                    function(){
                        $(this).addClass('jshover');
                    }, function(){
                        $(this).removeClass('jshover');
                    });
        }
    }
```

required jQuery Version here 1.2.6 for 1.3.x you have to change the browser check.

Comment: Sadly, since IE6 also doesn't support multiple classes in CSS properly, this will have limited utility if you attempt to apply this to elements with existing classes.

Answer (score 0):

There's Google's [ie7-js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/), but I'm not sure if it addresses anything other than transparent-png issues.

[Visibility inherit](http://www.visibilityinherit.com/) offers this [alternative](http://www.visibilityinherit.com/code/ie6-hover-javascript.php) that directly addresses the mouseOver/:hover problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about mouseover on non anchor tags, you could use jQuery to add an event handler to catch mouseover events.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be applicable for your context, but you could always just make a point of having your a elements be given the hover effect.  For example, in a navigational ul>li>a list, style the a elements with display:block and style them, rather than the lis.